# Why is my printf printing the wrong values?

Tags: c, printf

I can't figure out why my code is not working.  I am trying to create something similar to P2P file transfer where multiple threads simultaneously grab different parts of a file from a pre-existing server program.  The actual problem I am having right now, is much simpler, however.

Since you cannot pass multiple arguments into pthread_create, I created a structure that had the two pieces of information I want to pass.  I also created an array of pointers to these structures and initialize each one individually before passing it's pointer in.

```
printf("In thread: port=%d & ipAddr=%s\n",conn->port,conn->ipAddr);
```

When that line runs, everything prints out correctly with the correct port number and IP address.

```
printf("Size of chunk %d received by %lu on port %d: %d bytes\n",chunkNum,pthread_self(),conn->port,sizeRec);
```

However, when that line runs shortly after, the port number does not print out correctly.  Instead of 9210 and 9211, I get 0 and 134520848.  Otherwise, everything seems to be working so I'm thinking it may just be a printf problem of some sort, but I want to be sure before I move on to implementing the next part of my project.

If anyone has any idea why the same variable would print with one value and a completely different a few lines later when no changes were made, it would be very helpful for me.  I have included all of my code below for reference.  Thanks for your help!

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

char * file_name = "output.txt";
int nextChunk = 0;

pthread_mutex_t lock1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

struct connection{
  int port;
  char* ipAddr;
};

void* getFile(void* args) {
  int con_fd = 0;
  int ret = 0;  
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  struct connection* conn = (struct connection*)args;
  printf("In thread: port=%d & ipAddr=%s\n",conn->port,conn->ipAddr);

memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
//printf("port number: %d\n",conn->port);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(conn->port);
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(conn->ipAddr);
int sizeRec;
char buf[1024];
while(1) {
    con_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (con_fd == -1) {
        printf("Socket Error\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        return 0;
    }
    ret = connect(con_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    if (ret < 0) {
        printf("Connect error\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        return 0;
    }
    char chunkStr[128];
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
    int chunkNum = nextChunk++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
    sprintf(chunkStr,"%d",chunkNum);
    send(con_fd,chunkStr,128,0);
    sizeRec = recv(con_fd,buf,1024,0);
    printf("Size of chunk %d received by %lu on port %d: %d bytes\n",chunkNum,pthread_self(),conn->port,sizeRec);
    if (sizeRec <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
} 
/*FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w");
if (!f) {
    printf("Can't open %s for input. Program halting\n",filename);
    exit(0);
}*/
/*while ((sizeReceived = recv(sock,buf,1024,0)) > 0) {
    if (fwrite(buf,sizeof(char),sizeReceived,f) == -1) {
        printf("Error writing file");
        exit(0);
    }
}
fclose(f);*/
close(con_fd);
return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

if (argc < 3 || argc % 2 == 0) {
printf("Usage: ./client <ipaddr1> <port1> <ipaddr2> <port2> . . .\n");
return -1;
}
int numThreads = argc / 2;
pthread_t threads[numThreads];
struct connection** connections = malloc(sizeof(struct connection*)*numThreads);
//char* args[numThreads][2];
printf("numThreads: %d\n",numThreads);
for (int i=0; i<numThreads; i++) {
    connections[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct connection));
    connections[i]->ipAddr = argv[2*i+1];
    connections[i]->port = atoi(argv[2*i+2]);
    printf("port number: %d\n",connections[i]->port);
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, getFile, (void*)(connections[i]));
}
for (int i=0; i<numThreads; i++) {
    free(connections[i]);
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to `printf` the return value of `pthread_self`. Your problem might be somewhere else, but that's a good place to look first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is the second `for` loop in `main()`.

You first free the data structure and then call `pthread_join()`. Reverse these two statements and it should work reliable.

If you use Linux, I suggest to use valgrind tool, which easily helps to spot such issues. For windows I only know expensive commercial tools doing the same (like Purify).

Comment: We learned about Valgrind in my class and I have been using it.  While using Valgrind, I found the error you pointed out and I was definitely freeing memory before I was accessing it in some cases, so thank you for pointing this out.  As it turns out, this didn't fix the problem I was having.  In case anyone finds this in the future, I fixed that problem by replacing "char chunkStr[128]" with "char* chunkStr = calloc(sizeof(char),128).  I'm not sure why, but that was somehow effecting the output.

Comment: Replacing the stack variable with a heap variable moves only the storage place. If this affects your program behavior, you have a serious problem left (probably some sort of buffer overflow - but reading the code I don't see any reason). In my test the print worked with the suggested change, but I did only a simple I/O test. Again valgrind together with gdb usually are very good to find troubles of this type. :-)

Comment: @user2271605 the line `send(con_fd,chunkStr,128,0);` was accessing uninitialized data since it was sending all 128 bytes but you were  setting far fewer (with `sprintf(chunkStr,"%d",chunkNum);`). While that's undefined behavior and could in theory do anything, I agree with Dirk that if that fixed it, it's likely you also have another error somewhere. Probably unrelated, but you're also trying to print an `ssize_t` using `%d`, you should use the correct format string for your library (such as `%zd`).

Comment: The print statement is just temporary and was only for the purpose of making sure each thread was doing work, not just in one thread.  It was ultimately removed from the final version of my code so I wasn't worried about just using %d, even though I knew it was technically incorrect.  As for the other problem, I can't find any other errors in Valgrind so I'm not sure why those unitialized values were effecting the output.  However, the final product runs with no problems 100% of the time, even in Valgrind, so I'll just hope for the best!

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
for (int i=0; i<numThreads; i++) {
    free(connections[i]);
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
```

To :

```
for (int i=0; i<numThreads; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);        
    free(connections[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing.  That error was causing memory issues that I discovered in Valgrind, but unfortunately not the error I was experiencing.